# Unable to use SSH after changing DHCP to static IP in coreOS

Tags: networking, systemd, coreos

I could connect to coreOS through Putty in Windows10.
But after changing DHCP to static IP in coreOS, 
I suddenly became unable to use SSH through putty(cannot connect to coreOS through putty in Windows10).
I wonder why this happened, and how I could solve this problem.
I investigated status of ssh in coreOS. and it says inavtive.
What should I do to solve this problem?
If anyone knows please help me.
I have no clue... TT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sshd is inactive, you might be able to restart it.  I'd be interested whether you used networkd (as documented [here](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/network-config-with-networkd.html)) when you changed from DHCP to static IP, as I think that should have been picked up automagically by CoreOS.

If you are seeing that the following command shows sshd as "inactive (dead}":

```
sudo systemctl status sshd
```

You can start sshd with:

```
sudo systemctl start sshd
```

And just in case you need it  [here](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/customizing-sshd.html) is documentation on how to customize the ssh daemon.

Comment: yes, I used networkd documented in official coreos website to change from DHCP to static IP. I tried to restart it and it is active now but it still says: loaded (/usr/lib64/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)

Comment: And when I ping my gateway(192.168.0.1), it failed to ping(Destination Host Unreachabe)

Comment: ? what is the output of "sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd"?
Do you see "Active: active (running) ... "?
Do you see "<date> <host> systemd-networkd[<pid>]: <device>: Configured"  for your network device (e.g. eno2, or eth0)

Comment: that looks good.  What is the state of network device ens33?
    **ip a show dev ens33**

Comment: also look at the output of:

    `ip route` and
    `sudo journalctl -b | grep ens33`

Comment: I tried to type all commands you said and the result is as below: http://s29.postimg.org/4uu1p60rr/image.jpg

Comment: that output looks good too... Can you verify you still cannot ping the gateway?  If you cannot, and given the Network link seems to be active... Are you sure you're using the right subnet and mask?

Comment: Well.. I still cannot.. even though the subnet mask and gateway is right.. maybe should I try to use cloudconfig?

Comment: The problem was the lan cable did not work well, I fixed that cable and I could connect again. Thank you for helping me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your network unit was formatted correctly as is being accepted?

Did you restart networkd afterwards if you added the network unit manually? `sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd`

Are you using cloudconfig to add the network unit? See if there is anything in the journal: `journalctl _EXE=/usr/bin/coreos-cloudinit`

You can also validate your cloud-config here: https://coreos.com/validate/

Comment: I did as documentation in official coreos website, and restarted networkd after changing IP. but I am not using cloudconfig, because I am not very aware of it. When I typed journalctl _EXE=/usr/bin/coreos-cloudinit in coreOS, it said --No entries--